# I defined a list of arrays in c++ for representing a graph. But i can't seem to access the elements of the arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, list, arraylist

basically this is what i did, a list of int pointers to be used as a list of arrays:

```
#include <list>
list<int> *l;
l = new list<int>[V + 1];
```

I can push_back(integer) into l[x] to create the array at "x" position on the list and i get no error. But when i use l[x][some_index] to access an element of the array at position "x" in the list, this is the error i get:

> error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::__cxx11::list’ and ‘int’)

Can someone please help me with this?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::list` in C++ is implemented as a doubly-linked list. It does not support random access to its elements, therefore it does not have the `[]` operator available. You can use `front()` and `back()` to access the first and last elements, and you can use iterators to iterate and access the content of the list.

In your example, you are using `l[x][some_index]`. `l[x]` will give to the xth element of the dynamically allocated list of arrays. But then you are applying the `[]` operator on the `std::list` object this is returning. And that does not exist.

You are probably looking for using `std::vector`. This is a container of variable size that stores the elements contiguously in memory and therefore has random access to the elements and you can use the `[]` operator.

On the other hand, there is no reason for you to use pointers. You could have a vector of vectors (like `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`). If you do need to allocate things then use smart pointers, such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, depending on your needs.